# sorting strings in an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, object

I've been trying to sort string inside an object which is inside an array. By splitting the string into array, I successfully sorted the array. I turn the array back to string afterwards. but later when I printed the result, the object inside the array was the same as before. Here is my code:

```
 function merge(arr, needed_length){

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(arr[i]['A1'].split(', ').sort(function(a, b){
            return b - a;
        }).join(', '));

        console.log(arr[i]);
    }

}

console.log(merge([{A1:'8, 7, 9'}, {A1:'4, 8, 6'}, {A1:'2, 4, 3'}], 5));
```

and here is the printed result:

```
9, 8, 7
{ A1: '8, 7, 9' }
8, 6, 4
{ A1: '4, 8, 6' }
4, 3, 2
{ A1: '2, 4, 3' }
```

Can someone help me to understand why the object doesn't change? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You're sorting the array from `.split(' , ')`. This doesn't change the content of `arr[i]['A1']`

Comment: And why do you always log the first element in `arr` (`console.log(arr[0])`)? o.O

Comment: If I want to change the content of arr[i]['A1'], what should i do?

Comment: You need to *assign*.

Comment: I've changed it to ```console.log(arr[i])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the sorted string back to `A1`:

```js
function merge(arr){
    for(let obj of arr){
        obj.A1 = obj.A1.split(', ').sort((a, b) => b - a).join(', ');
    }
    return arr;
}

let arr = [{A1:'8, 7, 9'}, {A1:'4, 8, 6'}, {A1:'2, 4, 3'}];
merge(arr);
console.log(arr);
```